# How can I perform multiplication, using bitwise operators?

Tags: bit-manipulation, multiplication

I am working through a problem which I was able to solve, all but for the last piece—I am not sure how one can do multiplication using bitwise operators:

```
0*8 = 0

1*8 = 8

2*8 = 16

3*8 = 24

4*8 = 32
```

Is there an approach to solve this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To multiply by any value of 2 to the power of N (i.e., 2^N), shift the bits N times to the left.

```
0000 0001 = 1

times 4 = (2^2 => N = 2) = 2 bit shift : 0000 0100 = 4

times 8 = (2^3 -> N = 3) = 3 bit shift : 0010 0000 = 32
```

etc..

To divide, shift the bits to the right.

The bits are whole 1 or 0 - you can't shift by a part of a bit, thus if the number you're multiplying by is does not factor a whole value of N.
I.e.,

```
since: 17 = 16  + 1
thus:  17 = 2^4 + 1

therefore: x * 17 = (x * 16) + x in other words 17 x's
```

Thus to multiply by 17, you have to do a 4 bit shift to the left, and then add the original number again:

```
==> x * 17 = (x * 16) + x
==> x * 17 = (x * 2^4) + x
==> x * 17 = (x shifted to left by 4 bits) + x

so let x = 3 = 0000 0011

times 16 = (2^4 => N = 4) = 4 bit shift : 0011 0000 = 48

plus the x (0000 0011)
```

I.e.,

```
    0011 0000  (48)
+   0000 0011   (3)
=============
    0011 0011  (51)
```

[Charles Petzold has written a fantastic book 'Code'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735611319) that will explain all of this and more in the easiest of ways. I thoroughly recommend this.

Comment: right. it's not quite the same thing though. what if you want to  multiply 3*17

Answer (score 19):

To multiply two binary encoded numbers without a multiply instruction.
It would be simple to iteratively add to reach the product.

```
unsigned int mult(x, y)
unsigned int x, y;
{
    unsigned int reg = 0;

    while(y--)
        reg += x;
    return reg;
}
```

Using bit operations, the characteristic of the data encoding can be exploited.
As explained previously, a bit shift is the same as multiply by two.
Using this an adder can be used on the powers of two.

```
// multiply two numbers with bit operations

unsigned int mult(x, y)
unsigned int x, y;
{
    unsigned int reg = 0;

    while (y != 0)
    {
        if (y & 1)
        {
            reg += x;
        }
        x <<= 1;
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return reg;
}
```

Comment: What programming language? [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 10 years ago"*

Answer (score 3):

You'd factor the multiplicand into powers of 2.
3*17 = 3*(16+1) = 3*16 + 3*1
 ... = 0011b << 4 + 0011b

Comment: If this approach is used, doesn't that mean that multiplying a number by (2^n)-1 would be the *most* work for a processor?

Comment: One might ask himself how to get the splitted powers of 2 in an easy way... This is what https://stackoverflow.com/a/28158393/6280369 does... so in addition given answer: 3*17 = ???
=> 17 = b10001 = 16*1 + 8*0 + 4*0 +2*0 +1*1 
=> 3*17 = 1*1*3 + 0*2*3+0*4*3+0*8*3+1*16*3 (multiplying by powers of 2 is easy: shifting left 'power' times, simply said add a zero) = 1*3 + 1*3*2*2*2*2 = b11 + b110000 = b110011 = 3 + 48 = 51

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
public static int multi(int x, int y) {
    boolean neg = false;
    if(x < 0 && y >= 0) {
        x = -x;
        neg = true;
    }
    else if(y < 0 && x >= 0) {
        y = -y;
        neg = true;
    }else if(x < 0 && y < 0) {
        x = -x;
        y = -y;
    }

    int res = 0;
    while(y != 0) {
        if((y & 1) == 1)
            res += x;
        x <<= 1;
        y >>= 1;
    }
    return neg ? (-res) : res;
}
```

Comment: What programming language? [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be a left shift.  8 is 2^3, so left shift 3 bits:

2 << 3 = 8

Comment: Shouldn't it be 2 << 3 = 16? 2 = 00000010, therefore, if you left shift the number '2' three times you would get 00010000 = 16 (not 8).

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a recursive multiplication problem without the `*` operator and came up with a solution that was informed by the top answer here.

I thought it was worth posting because I really like the explanation in the top answer here, but wanted to expand on it in a way that:

1. Had a function representation.
2. Handled cases where your "remainder" was arbitrary.

This only handles positive integers, but you could wrap it  in a check for negatives like some of the other answers.

Python:

```py
def rec_mult_bitwise(a,b):
    # Base cases for recursion
    if b == 0:
        return 0
    if b == 1:
        return a

    # Get the most significant bit and the power of two it represents
    msb = 1
    pwr_of_2 = 0
    while True:
        next_msb = msb << 1
        if next_msb > b:
            break
        pwr_of_2 += 1
        msb = next_msb
        if next_msb == b:
            break

    # To understand the return value, remember:
    # 1: Left shifting by the power of two is the same as multiplying by the number itself (ie x*16=x<<4)
    # 2: Once we've done that, we still need to multiply by the remainder, hence b - msb
    return (a << pwr_of_2) + rec_mult_bitwise(a, b - msb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a bitwise operator reduces the time complexity.

**In C++:**

```
#include<iostream>
using name space std;

int main(){
   int a, b, res = 0;           // read the elements
   cin>>a>>b;

   // find the small number to reduce the iterations

   small = (a<b)?a:b;           // small number using ternary operator
   big = (small^a)?a:b;         // big number using bitwise XOR operator

   while(small > 0)
   {
      if(small & 1)
      {
         res += big;
      }
      big = big << 1;           // it increases the number << is big * (2 power of big)
      small = small >> 1;       // it decreases the number >> is small / (2 power of small)
   }
   cout<<res;
}
```

**In Python:**

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
res = 0

small = a if(a < b) else b
big  = a if(small ^ a) else b

def multiplication(small, big):
    res = 0
    while small > 0:
        if small & 1:
            res += big
        big = big << 1
        small = small >> 1

        return res

 answer = multiplication(small, big)
 print(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
see if this could help answer your question...

#include<stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b) // bitwise addition
{
    
    int carry = (a & b)<<1;
    int result = a^b;
    if(carry == 0)
        return result;
    else
        add(carry,result);
}
int mul(int a, int b) //bitwise multiplicaton using addition
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<a; i++)
    {
        result = add(result,b);
    }
    return result;
}
void main()
{
    int a = 4, b = 4;
    printf("%d",mul(a,b));
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great when min(a,b) <= 60,000 so that the code will be sub-million operations. That's still quite a low bound though.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
-(int)multiplyNumber:(int)num1 withNumber:(int)num2
{
    int mulResult = 0;
    int ithBit;

    BOOL isNegativeSign = (num1 < 0 && num2 > 0) ||
                          (num1 > 0 && num2 < 0);
    num1 = abs(num1);
    num2 = abs(num2);

    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(num2)*8; i++)
    {
        ithBit = num2 & (1<<i);
        if(ithBit > 0)
        {
            mulResult += (num1 << i);
        }

    }

    if (isNegativeSign)
    {
        mulResult = ((~mulResult) + 1);
    }

    return mulResult;
}
```

Comment: What programming language? [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)?

Answer (score -1):

I have just realized that this is the same answer as the previous one. LOL sorry.

```
public static uint Multiply(uint a, uint b)
{
   uint c = 0;
   while(b > 0)
   {
      c += ((b & 1) > 0) ? a : 0;
      a <<= 1;
      b >>= 1;
   }
   return c;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this is a duplicate answer then you can help   manage the site by deleting your own post

Answer (score -2):

```
def multiply(x, y):
     return x << (y >> 1)
```

You would want to halve the value of y, hence y shift bits to the right once (y >> 1) and shift the bits again x times to the left to get your answer x << (y >> 1).

Comment: What programming language? [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)?