# How to multiple two positive integers without multiplication or division operators or loops

Tags: c#

I need to multiply two integers without using multiplication or division operators, any built in Multiply functions, or loops.

I have managed to do multiplication with with a loop, but I don't get how to do so without loops.

Here is my solution with a loop:

```
Public Double(Double x, Double y)
{
 Double Result;
 Result =0;
 If(x==0 || y==0)
 {
   Result = 0;
  }
 else
 {
  for(int i=0; i<=y; i++)
   {
     Result = Result + x;   
   }
 }
        return Result;
}
```

Comment: You accept doubles, and yet your method only works if `y` is an integer.  Do you *actually* need to support floating point numbers?  You also don't support negative numbers properly.

Comment: no I don't, let consider I am working on integer numbers

Comment: Then make your method accept an integer type, not a floating point type.

Comment: correct...............

Comment: Oh, and you also have a bunch of compiler errors in your code, if you're going to proport that the code is working code, you should be  posting working code.

Comment: I have tested code and it does work,... just for simplicity I am consider interger

Comment: but I main question is how I do without loop

Comment: The code that you posted doesn't work.  The code that you posted doesn't even compile, for a multitude of reasons.  If you have actual working code, then post that working code, because this isn't it.

Comment: Do you have any restriction on parameters?

Comment: recursion counts as a loop?

Comment: lets say you've earned a downvote with that last comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below in your function

```
        List<int> temp = new List<int>();
        temp.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(x,y));

        var result = test.Sum();
```

where your 'y' variable would be an integer count. However I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

> I need to multiply two integers without using multiplication or division operators, any built in Multiply functions, or loops.

Reading the condition of your question, I think that the idea here is to use a smarter way for calculation, for example **bitwise operations**.

Based on the answers in [How to perform multiplication, using bitwise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722004/how-to-perform-multiplication-using-bitwise-operators) I suggest the following solution for your problem:

```
    public int MultiplyBitwise(int a, int b)
    {
        int product = 0;
        while (b > 0)
        {
            product += ((b & 1) > 0) ? a : 0;
            a <<= 1;
            b >>= 1;
        }

        return product;
    }
```