# How to correctly multiply two colors with byte components?

Tags: c#, colors, bit-shift, multiplication

I would like to multiply two colors whose components are `byte` but I'm running into inconsistent results.

When components are `float` it's exact and easy:

```
float a = 1.0f;
float b = 1.0f;
float c = a * b;
```

When components are `byte`, I vaguely remember there's some bit-shifting, however my formula is clearly missing something:

```
byte a = 255;
byte b = 255;
byte c = (byte)((a * b) >> 8);
// 255 * 255 = 65025 then 65025 >> 8 = 254
// obviously, adding 1 to the result is just wrong
```

**Note:**

I can't use a `Color` type from popular frameworks such as Forms or WPF, as my project acts as an abstraction layer that is to be re-used from different frameworks.

**Question:**

What is the right algorithm for for multiplying `byte` colors using bit-shifts ?

Comment: You could always normalize the byte values into floats, do the multiplication, and then convert back: `float fA = (float)(a / 255.0); float fB = (float)(b / 255.0); float fC = fA * fB; byte c = (byte)(255 * fC);`.

Comment: Is `(byte)((a * b + 0xFF) >> 8)` the result you want?

Comment: @itsme86 I know there is this failproof solution but if I could avoid using floats since I'm doing a bunch of conversions that'd be great.

Comment: @harold unfortunately that fails on `(128 * 128 + 255) >> 8 == 64`

Comment: @Aybe can you give a list of desired input/output pairs then? 128*128 = 64 looks pretty legitimate to me, as 128 = 0.5.

Comment: @harold sorry, you're right ! :) feel free to add answer

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919663/how-does-photoshop-blend-two-images-together) very helpful to know what to do. - And to do the shifting [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722004/how-to-perform-multiplication-using-bitwise-operators)

Comment: @TaW Excellent, thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold)'s comment worked for me:

```
(byte)((a * b + 0xFF) >> 8)
```

I am reposting his comment as an answer to make his solution easier to find.